# Sybase Database Error: Invalid data conversion

Tags: sql, database, sybase

I need help with this Query, I'm making some calculations based on some results, but I'm receiving the following error:

> Sybase Database Error: Invalid data conversion.

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT
      DC.DIM_DATE.DATE_ID,
      DC.DIM_E_RAN_UCELL.RBS_ID,
      (SUM(DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.pmSumBestDchPsIntRabEstablish)+SUM(DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.pmSumFachPsIntRabEstablish)+SUM(DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.pmSumBestPsHsAdchRabEstablish)+SUM(DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.pmSumBestPsEulRabEstablish))/720 AS '3G_DATA_ERLANG',
      (SUM(DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.pmSumBestCs12Establish)+SUM(DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.pmSumBestAmr12200RabEstablish)+SUM(DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.pmSumBestAmr7950RabEstablish)+SUM(DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.pmSumBestAmr5900RabEstablish)+SUM(DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.pmSumBestAmr4750RabEstablish)+SUM(DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.pmSumBestAmrWbRabEstablish)+SUM(DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.pmSumBestAmrNbMmRabEstablish))/720 AS '3G_SPEECH_ERLANG',
      (100*(SUM(DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.pmTotNoRrcConnectReqCsSucc)/(1+SUM(DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.pmTotNoRrcConnectReqCs)-SUM(DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.pmNoLoadSharingRrcConnCs))*(SUM(DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.pmNoRabEstablishSuccessSpeech)+SUM(DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.pmNoRabEstablishSuccessCs64)+SUM(DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.pmRabEstablishEcSuccess))/(SUM(DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.pmRabEstablishEcAttempt)+SUM(DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.pmNoRabEstablishAttemptSpeech)+SUM(DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.pmNoRabEstablishAttemptCs64)-SUM(DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.pmNoDirRetryAtt)))) AS '3G_CSSR_CS'
    FROM
      DC.DIM_DATE,
      DC.DIM_TIME,
      DC.DIM_E_RAN_UCELL,
      DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW
    WHERE
      (DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.HOUR_ID=DC.DIM_TIME.HOUR_ID and DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.MIN_ID=DC.DIM_TIME.MIN_ID)
      AND  (DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.DATE_ID=DC.DIM_DATE.DATE_ID)
      AND  (DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.OSS_ID=DC.DIM_E_RAN_UCELL.OSS_ID)
      AND  (DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.RNC=DC.DIM_E_RAN_UCELL.RNC_ID)
      AND  (DC.DC_E_RAN_UCELL_RAW.UtranCell=DC.DIM_E_RAN_UCELL.UCELL_ID)
      AND  
      (
       DC.DIM_DATE.DATE_ID  IN  ('2017-08-14')
       AND
       DC.DIM_E_RAN_UCELL.RBS_ID  IN ('DN1U0441')
      )
    GROUP BY
      DC.DIM_DATE.DATE_ID,
      DC.DIM_E_RAN_UCELL.RBS_ID
```

The problem is with the last row of the SELECT statement, without it the result is this:

```
DATE_ID RBS_ID  3G_DATA_ERLANG  3G_SPEECH_ERLANG
8/14/2017   DN1U0441    421.8541    33.5055
```

When is included I got this error:

```
Lookup Error - Sybase Database Error: Invalid data conversion
```

Any Help? Is **Sybase ASE DataBase**

Comment: Are you sure that's ASE and not SQLAnywhere or IQ, as that's not a complete ASE error message; I'd start by suggesting you run the query via the `isql` command line tool and then update your question with the actual/complete error message; at some point it may also become necessary to provide the DDL for the tables involved.

Comment: Is Sybase ASE, but I can use isql from the command line too, so I'll run it and I'll let you know in a few minutes, thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, is iqisql confirming now

Comment: One of the many fields in your last `SUM()` is probably not able to be summed.. ie. it has alpha characters.  Start with `SUM(first field)` then add each field back in until it breaks.  Then you've found your issue.

Comment: I'll check, thanks

Comment: I'm unable to find the error